# C++ codeblocks ide errors?

Tags: c++, ide, codeblocks, portable-executable

I have codeblocks installed on an HD, the compiler works fine. The reason its on an HD is because my school doesn't like people installing things onto the computers...

main.cpp works fine. If I coded everything in this I wouldn't run into any problems. The only problem is, if I add a class to the project I get several errors.

[image]

I touched the classes at all, they compile fine on my computer at home. Is it because the project is not saved in a proper directory/folder? I have a folder for the project inside the codeblocks folder on the HD, so it should be able to find the theclass.h and theclass.cpp files.

If main.cpp also didn't work, it would make more sense. But why is it that the new class won't work?

Comment: @Grammin I never blamed the IDE. Its definitely an issue with where the files are located. So I'm blaming my HD

Comment: yea i realized that I read your question title wrong.  Are you on a windows/linux machine, you could just compile it without the editor on the command line.

Comment: Check the include paths your passing to the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `theclass.h` is in the `include` directory, a sibling directory of `src`. You should either get both files in the same directory, or use `#include "../theclass.h"` if you absolutely must keep the files where they are.

Answer (score 2):

yeah actually codeblocks has this error what you have to do is get the classes namely the .cpp and the .h out of the folder and get them in the root of the project so cut them and paste them where the main.cpp is and it should work also what you can do is put #include "source/theclass.cpp" and u can also solve it that way(also do the same for the .h

Answer (score 1):

Codeblocks moves the files to seperate include and source directories. This is why `#include "theclass.h"` leads to an error.